# How to return rows by MySQL in order of ids given inside IN function?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table named `resources`. I am now using this query:

```
Select 
    Resource.id, Resource.status
from
    resources as Resource
where
    Resource.id IN ('53f4c1b8-7b60-42c9-ad88-324d16091b4e' , '53f4cb98-f5c4-448d-9bd4-3ac516091b4e',
        '53ccf77e-5ce0-4868-aa2e-395716091b4e',
        '53f4c9ba-693c-4c17-a16f-36d516091b4e')
```

When I queried, I got rows returned based on ordering `id`. ie.,The row having 2nd id is returned first. Well, it works like this. The rows are returned as per the ids in ascending order. Now, I need to return rows as per the input I have given. ie.,53f4c1b8-7b60-42c9-ad88-324d16091b4e should return as first row. What should I change in this query to get like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where
    Resource.id IN ('53f4c1b8-7b60-42c9-ad88-324d16091b4e' , '53f4cb98-f5c4-448d-9bd4-3ac516091b4e',
        '53ccf77e-5ce0-4868-aa2e-395716091b4e',
        '53f4c9ba-693c-4c17-a16f-36d516091b4e')
ORDER BY FIELD( Resource.id,'53f4c1b8-7b60-42c9-ad88-324d16091b4e' , '53f4cb98-f5c4-448d-9bd4-3ac516091b4e',
        '53ccf77e-5ce0-4868-aa2e-395716091b4e',
        '53f4c9ba-693c-4c17-a16f-36d516091b4e')
```